# How to add custom validation to an angular component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this angular component where I like to add a custom input validator ([see plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/awD9N2KOwVSkaBlcFs8P/)).

I'm trying to access the `ngModelController` in the `$onInit` function. But it seams that the form is not populated at this time. Later on in the `sendEmail()` function it's no problem to access the the input model controller. How can I access the `ngModelController` and add a custom validator?

emailInput.js

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  function EmailInputController($log) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.$onInit = function() {
      // ctrl.myForm.myEmailInput is not populated 
      //$log.debug("Email view value is: "+(ctrl.myForm.myEmailInput.$viewValue));
    };

    ctrl.sendEmail = function() {
      $log.debug("EmailInputController.sendEmail");
      $log.debug("Email view value is: " + (ctrl.myForm.myEmailInput.$viewValue));
    };

  }

  angular.module('emailInputApp').component('emailInput', {
    templateUrl: 'emailInput.html',
    controller: EmailInputController,
  });
})(window.angular);
```

emailInput.html

```
<form name="$ctrl.myForm">
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input name="myEmailInput" type="email" ng-model="$ctrl.email" required maxlength="15">
  <button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.sendEmail()">Send Email</button>
  <p>Your Email addres is {{$ctrl.email}}</p>
  <div ng-messages="$ctrl.myForm.myEmailInput.$error" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">Please enter an email address.</div>
    <div ng-message="email">This field must be a valid email address.</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">This field can be at most 15 characters long.</div>
  </div>
  <code>
    {{$ctrl.myForm.myEmailInput | json}}
  </code>
</form>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/YQfGAsix1DON4ff3EWxz?p=preview but I do not recommend it.

Comment: And why is this not recommended?

Comment: You should separate concerns, it really does not look like it is good idea to do validation in parent component. Ihmo separate directive that does that and only that is better solution. Beside adding watcher seems a little bit ugly. If you lets say change name of controller it will break.

Comment: Well I think that depends on the design. Email Input is just an example for a much more complex input component. Having all the logic for this component in one controller doesn't look so bad to me. - Feel free to add your original comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Well, yea that is mostly design choice. Performance wise it not that bad, cos watcher is removed when not needed anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/YQfGAsix1DON4ff3EWxz?p=preview

You can add watcher and remove it when not needed anymore.

```
var removeWatch = $scope.$watch('$ctrl.myForm', function () {
        $log.debug("Email view value is: " + (ctrl.myForm.myEmailInput.$modelValue));

        removeWatch();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('validateEmail', function() {
  var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;

  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: '',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      // only apply the validator if ngModel is present and Angular has added the email validator
      if (ctrl && ctrl.$validators.email) {

        // this will overwrite the default Angular email validator
        ctrl.$validators.email = function(modelValue) {
          return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || EMAIL_REGEXP.test(modelValue);
        };
      }
    }
  };
});
```

And simply add

```
<input type='email' validate-email name='email' id='email' ng-model='email' required>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that I can write a directive to add custom validation. But that's not what I asked for.